# Is there an easy way to reset an swift app to clear all variables and seemingly start from the beginning?

Tags: swift, xcode

At the end of my apps game I want to reset so the game can be played again.

Ive tried the recommended method shown in the code but it causes:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error to occur.

```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:       "ViewController")
        var viewcontrollers =     self.navigationController!.viewControllers
        viewcontrollers.removeLast()
        viewcontrollers.append(vc)
        self.navigationController!.setViewControllers(viewcontrollers,   animated: true)
```

Expect to be able to reset the game/app and proceed with a new game by pressing a button.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) 
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")

        let transition: UIView.AnimationOptions = .transitionFlipFromLeft
        let rootviewcontroller: UIWindow = ((UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window)!)!
        rootviewcontroller.rootViewController = vc
        let mainwindow = (UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!)!
        UIView.transition(with: mainwindow, duration: 0.4, options: transition, animations: nil, completion: nil)
```

Comment: same error occurs. you'd think there'd be a super easy way to do this considering this function is highly necessary

Answer (score 0):

If your (re)starting `ViewController` class is the `rootViewController` of your `UINavigationController` then you can simply call:

```
navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Try to avoid the bang operator (`!`) to avoid similar force-unwrap crashes, for example you could safely unwrap the `navigationController` like so:

```
if let navController = navigationController {
    navController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```